# How to show radio button from database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, radio-button

i have read user guide and tutorial about this, i'm still new bie at this time in code igniter so hard understanding it, 
how can i checked in radio button ?

Big Thanks

here is my controller

```html
public function updateProduct($id) 
 {
  $data['product'] = $this->products_model->getProduct($id); 
     $this->load->view('update_product_view', $data);
  }
 
 public function updateProductDb()
 {
   $data=array(
     'nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
     'umur'=>$this->input->post('umur'),
     'hoby'=>$this->input->post('hoby'),
     'jk'=>$this->input->post('jk'),
     'alamat'=>$this->input->post('alamat'));
   $condition['id'] = $this->input->post('id'); 
  $this->products_model->updateProduct($data, $condition);
  redirect('products'); 
  }
```

```html
here is my model

<?php
//File products_model.php
 class Products_model extends CI_Model  {
  function __construct() { parent::__construct(); } function getAllProducts() {
  //select semua data yang ada pada table msProduct $this--->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from("anggota");
  return $this->db->get();
 }
 
 //iNI BERFUNGSI UNTUK GET DATA YANG DI PILIH BERDASARKAN ID ATAU USER YANG KLIK */
 function getProduct($id)
 {
  //select produk berdasarkan id yang dimiliki 
        $this->db->where('id', $id); //Akan melakukan select terhadap row yang memiliki productId sesuai dengan productId yang telah dipilih
        $this->db->select("*"); // SELECT ALL
        $this->db->from("anggota"); //TABEL
        
        return $this->db->get();
 }
 function addProduct($data)
 {
 //untuk insert ke database
 $this->db->insert('anggota',$data);
 }
 
 function updateProduct($data, $condition)
 {
  //update produk
        $this->db->where($condition); //Hanya akan melakukan update sesuai dengan condition yang sudah ditentukan
        $this->db->update('anggota', $data); //Melakukan update terhadap table msProduct sesuai dengan data yang telah diterima dari controller
 }
 function deleteProduct($id)
 {
  //delete produk berdasarkan id
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('anggota');
 }
 
 }
```

and this view

```html
<input type="text" name="jk" value="<?php echo $detail->jk; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add it in the controller before you call your view

```
    $radio_data = array(
    'name'        => 'jk',
    'id'          => 'jk',
    'value'       => $detail->jk,
    'checked'     => TRUE,
    'style'       => 'margin:10px',
    );

$data['jk']=form_radio($radio_data);
```

Comment: it's solved by using this father

<input type="checkbox" name="hoby" value="Lari" <?php echo set_checkbox('hoby', '($detail->hoby=="Lari")'); ?> />Lari
       <input type="checkbox" name="hoby" value="Berenang" <?php echo set_checkbox('hoby', '($detail->hoby=="Berenang")'); ?> />Berenang